# rhc setup proxy issue - You are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: installation, proxy, openshift

I'm trying to setup rhc to install an OpenShift app and when I try to do:

```
rhc setup --debug
```

After setting up the proxy (set HTTP_PROXY=http://...) It fails with the message:

```
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

The complete debug answer (deleting personal info) is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>rhc setup --debug
DEBUG: Using config file C:/Users/xxxxx/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running server_stage

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online: openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|

You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Response: 403 {"Server"=>"squid", "Mime-Version"=>"1.0", "Date"=>"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 09:11:21 GMT", "Content-Type"=>"text/html", "Content-Length"=>"955"
 "X-Squid-Error"=>"ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0", "X-Cache"=>"MISS from myproxy.proxy.es", "X-Cache-Lookup"=>"NONE from myproxy.proxy.es:80", "Connection"=>"close"}

-------------
DEBUG: Response did not include a message from server: unexpected nil

You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running through a proxy?  It looks like a personal proxy is blocking access to openshift for you. (maybe a corporate proxy or firewall?)

Comment: Yes, I'm under a corporate proxy but this message is shown after setting up it. I mean, if I don't setup the proxy, the message is different.

Comment: You need to check with your IT department to have them allow access to openshift through your proxy.